# How can i display the name of the MenuCard, the MenuCardCategories and the associated MenuCardFood in the .html document with jinja2?

Tags: django, jinja2

i want to buld a menuCard, with categories and food.
It should be possible to create multiple menusCards.

## #My Try

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb9rR.png)

How can i display the name of the MenuCard, the MenuCardCategories and the associated MenuCardFood in the .html document with jinja2?
The result should look like this...

## #first menuCard

menuCardName 
menuCardCategoryName 
foodName 
foodName 
foodName

menuCardCategoryName 
foodName 
foodName 
foodName

## #second menuCard

menuCardName 
menuCardCategoryName 
foodName 
foodName

Comment: Please post code, not images of your code.  This helps us search, and try out the code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had not found a suitable tool at the time. In the future I will use codePile for this purpose

Comment: You're welcome!  You don't need a special tool.  You can just copy and paste, then format it easily using one of the methods described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/801002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the `MenuCard` objects and group the related `MenuCardFood` items by their category. Possible soltuion would be:

```py
objects_list = []

for menu in MenuCard.objects.all():
    menu_context = {'menu': menu, 'categories': []}
    categories = menu.menuCard_menuCardFood.values('menuCardCategories').distinct()

    for category in categories:
        category_context = {'category': category}
        related_food_list = menu.menuCard_menuCardFood.filter(menuCardCategories=category)
        category_context.update({'food_list': related_food_list})
        menu_context['categories'].append(category_context)

    objects_list.append(menu_context)
```

The above code should generate:

```
[
    {"menu": MenuCardObject1, "categories": ["category": MenuCardCategoryObject, "food_list": <QuerySet of MenuCardFood objects>],
    {"menu": MenuCardObject2, "categories": ["category": MenuCardCategoryObject, "food_list": <QuerySet of MenuCardFood objects>],
    {"menu": MenuCardObject3, "categories": ["category": MenuCardCategoryObject, "food_list": <QuerySet of MenuCardFood objects>],
]
```

Comment: hi i'm nooby, can u tell me where to set your code?
Must i write it in the models.py or in the views.py?

Comment: @Ping hi, you need to paste it in the views.py, and pass it as a context to the template